# HTML canvas updates too many times after resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas in which I animate stuff. I listen to the window resize event, update the canvas size and start the recursive drawing again. But it seems like the old draw() calls continue and this causes the animation to go faster than intended.
Here is the code:

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var frameCount = 0;
var count = 0;

var rectDistance = 100;
var rectSize = 72;
var rectOffset = (rectDistance - rectSize) / 2;
var angleSpeed = 1;

var draw = function() {
  count++;

  var xCount = canvas.width / rectDistance;
  var yCount = canvas.height / rectDistance;

  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < xCount; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < yCount; j++) {

      context.save();

      var r = Math.round(i / xCount * 255);
      var g = Math.round(j / xCount * 255);

      xPos = i * rectDistance + rectOffset + Math.sin(j + frameCount / 20) * 10;
      yPos = j * rectDistance + rectOffset + Math.cos(i + frameCount / 20) * 10;

      context.translate(xPos + rectSize / 2, yPos + rectSize / 2);
      context.rotate(frameCount / 100 * angleSpeed * Math.sin(frameCount / 500) * 5);

      context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + ",0,1)";
      context.fillRect(-rectSize / 2, -rectSize / 2, rectSize, rectSize);
      context.restore();
    }
  }

  frameCount = frameCount + 1;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
};

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resizeCanvas();
  }, 500);
}, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  draw();
}

// count the calls of draw() per second -> it's increasing on window.resize
function drawCalls() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("draw() called " + count + " times");
    count = 0;
    drawCalls();
  }, 1000)
}
drawCalls();

// start the loop
resizeCanvas();
```

How I can prevent the old draw() calls continue their recursive execution on resize?

Here is a codepen with the same issue: http://codepen.io/Sebkasanzew/pen/GZGZVP

Comment: If you don't stop your loop, why do you call draw in the resize event ? btw resize event will likely fire at higher rate than rAF. [forked Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNxEMN)

Comment: Calling draw() outside the resize event solves the problem. But then the creation of the drawn objects isn't executed again, right? But this solves at least the issue for this example, thanks.
Isn't there another way?

Comment: for a forever running animation, I would do it in two separate steps : an app update one and a drawing one. on resize you just call the app update, resetting all the variables and your drawing function will just consume the variables at each frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to cancel the `setTimeout()` - I would suggest the following:

```
var timer;

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  cancelAnimationFrame(timer);                  // cancel previous request
  timer = requestAnimationFrame(function() {    // create a new request
    resizeCanvas();
  })
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!